# Saiku cannot find JDBC driver for oracle connection

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jdbc, mondrian, saiku

I'm using the all-in-one version of saiku and trying to connect it to my oracle DB.

When starting saiku-server i got an error saying that it couldn't find the jdbc driver for oracle even if i put the driver in

> saiku-server\tomcat\webapps\saiku\WEB-INF\libojdbc14.jar

here's my connection file :

> saiku-server\tomcat\webapps\saiku\WEB-INF\classes\saiku-datasources\foodmart

```
type=OLAP
name=foodmart
driver=mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
location=jdbc:oracle:thin:mondrian_user/mondrian_user@localhost:1521:XE;Catalog=res:foodmart/FoodMart.xml;JdbcDrivers=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;
username=mondrian_user
password=mondrian_user
```

The connection is successful with dbms like mysql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most probably not related, but `ojdbc14.jar` is totally outdated and should not be used any longer (unless you are using Java **1.4**). Current Oracle JDBC drivers are named `ojdbc6.jar` or `ojdbc7.jar`

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name for your quick answer.
I'm using oracle 10g and when using "ojdbc6.jar" i got another error saying
    invalid connection string format a valid format is: "host:port:sid"

https://community.oracle.com/thread/372542

I'm using JDK1.7 ...

Comment: I changed the connection string and got :     driver:mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
    url:jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE;Catalog=res:foodmart/FoodMart.xml;Jdbc
    Drivers=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Answer (score 1):

You should add all JDBC drivers to `saiku-server/tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/lib` folder. It works with mysql because there already is jdbc driver in correct folder (`mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar`).

Saiku has a [documentation](http://docs.analytical-labs.com/saiku/documentation/2013/08/15/datasources.html) how to add new jdbc drivers.

Comment: Thats it? I can see "INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/local/saiku/tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/lib/phoenix-4.6.0-HBase-1.1-client.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class" then I got error "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:zookeeper" :/

Comment: @ThomasDecaux I don't get your comment. My answer was valid at the time I wrote it, but this is almost two years ago. If it is not valid anymore, feel free to edit my answer or post your own answer. I am not using Saiku anymore so I won't be able to make any further suggestions on this.

Comment: My poor english ;-( just asking if there are other things to setup in addition of adding the jar. Thanks you.